# Remove values in dataframe based on other columns

Tags: python, dataframe, date, filter

I have dataframe that looks like this (order of items should not matter)

| Id | date | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2023-01-01 | in progress |
| 01 | 2023-01-02 |  |
| 01 | 2023-01-03 | in progress |
| 01 | 2023-01-04 | done |
| 02 | 2023-01-01 | in progress |
| 02 | 2023-01-02 |  |

from it I need to remove all items that status was reset to empty based on id and date order so it will look like this

| Id | date | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2023-01-03 | in progress |
| 01 | 2023-01-04 | done |

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input? (Code to construct the DataFrame)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dates are already sorted within each group, you can use a reversed [`goupby.cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummin.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df[df.loc[::-1, 'status'].notnull().groupby(df['Id']).cummin()]
```

Or:

```
out = df[~df.loc[::-1, 'status'].isnull().groupby(df['Id']).cummax()]
```

If the dates are not sorted:

```
out = df[df.sort_values(by='date', ascending=False)['status'].notnull().groupby(df['Id']).cummin()]
```

Output:

```
   Id        date       status
2   1  2023-01-03  in progress
3   1  2023-01-04         done
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1,1,1,1,2,2],
                   'date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02'],
                   'status': ['in progress', float('nan'), 'in progress', 'done', 'in progress', float('nan')]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```py
# sort the dataframe (if necessary)
df = df.sort_values(["Id", "date"]).reset_index(drop=True)

df = df.groupby("Id", group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda x: x.loc[x["status"].eq("").idxmax() + 1 :]
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Id        date       status
2   1  2023-01-03  in progress
3   1  2023-01-04         done
```

---

Note: replace `.eq("")` with `.isna()` if the empty values are NaNs.

Comment: it will not work in case there are two or more empty status values, it will find only first and output other empty values